# How do i send an automatic mail after the execution of suite in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For my project an Email should be sent automatically with the results attained after execution of Suite in selenium. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: be more clear and a specific answer to this question is not possible.

Comment: There's lot of documentation available for the same.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hi answer to this question depends on the perspective

1.if you are running in `continuous integration with jenkins` please configure your jenkins it will send mail to the sender automatically once the job is done.

2.if you are using TestNG or jUnit then you can configure your mailer in

```
@AfterTest
public void SendMail(){  // your code to send mail e.g gmail. }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below detailed steps to send automatic emails after selenium test execution,this post is available in the official Selenium blogs as well.

http://www.assertselenium.com/java/emailable-reports-for-selenium-scripts/